# $x_n \in V_{n+1} \setminus V_n$, and $x_n \to p$. Show that $p \in \partial V$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Suppose $\{V_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a collection of open sets in $(X, d)$ such that $V_{n} \subset V_{n+1}$. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that $x_n \in V_{n+1} \setminus V_n$ and suppose $\{x_n\}$ converges to $p \in X$. Show that $p \in \partial V$ where $V = \cup_{n=1}^\infty V_n$.

It is not difficult to visualize that $x_n$ converges to the boundary of $V$, but I do not know how to prove it. I know that a convergent sequence in $\overline{V}$ should converge to $p \in \overline{V}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all note that all the elements in the sequence indeed belong to $\overline{V}$, hence the limit is also in $\overline{V}$. Now we will show that $p\notin V$. Suppose $p\in V$. Then by the definition of $V$ there is some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p\in V_k$. Since $V_k$ is open there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that the ball $B_{\epsilon}(p)$ is contained in $V_k$. Now, we know that $x_n\to p$ and hence:

$\exists (n_0\in\mathbb{N})\forall (n\geq n_0)\ [d(x_n, p)<\epsilon]$

And hence for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $x_n\in B_{\epsilon}(p)\subseteq V_k$, which contradicts the definition of the sequence. (because if $n>k$ then $x_n\notin V_k$)

So we showed that $p\in\overline{V}\setminus V$, hence it must be a point at the boundary of $V$.

Comment: Looks like a good answer, I would just add that, since $V$ is open, $\overline{V} \setminus V = \overline{V}\setminus \text{int}(V) = \partial V$.

Comment: That's also true. Though even if $V$ wasn't open, $p\notin V$ implies $p\notin  \text{int}(V)$ anyway. And $p\in\overline{V}$ implies that $p$ can't be in the exterior of $V$.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking about it wrong. We have $\overline{V} \setminus V \subset \partial V$, so what you showed is enough.

Comment: It may be Beyond-the-Scope™ of the current question, but it's nice to note that this holds in the more general case where $X$ is any topological space, not just a metric space, and your proof still works by just changing $\epsilon$s and balls to more general basis elements.

Comment: Yeah, and in a general topological space the proof might be even a bit shorter, because there the definition of convergence simply says that every open neighborhood of the limit must contain all but finite number of elements from the sequence. (so then we could immediately say that starting from some index all elements belong to $V_k$). However, I don't know if OP is familiar with topological spaces in general so in my answer I decided to go with the definitions of a metric space.

Answer (score 1):

Because the $V$ is the union of open sets, it is open and hence $V = \text{int}(V)$.
Since all $x_n$ lie in $V$, their limit $x$ lies in $\overline{V}$, as you yourself said.
All that remains to show is that $x\not\in V$.
To that end, a simple lemma is useful.

---

> **Lemma:** For each $m\in\Bbb N$ with $1\leqslant m \leqslant n$, we have that $x_n\not\in V_m$.

*Proof:*
Because of the chain of inclusions of the $V$s, if $x_n\in V_m$ for some $m\leqslant n$ we would have that $x_n\in V_{n}$.
This would contradict $x_n\in V_{n+1}\setminus V_n$. $\,\,\square$

---

Now, suppose $x\in V$.
If that were the case, then there would be some $k$ with $x\in V_k$.

Each neighborhood of $x$ must contain infinitely many of the $x_n$.
Because $V_k$ is open, there is some neighborhood of $x$ contained entirely in $V_k$.
However, by the lemma, for all $n\geqslant k$, we have $x_n\not\in V_{k}$.
This contradiction shows that our supposition that $x\in V$ must be false, as we set out to prove.

---

This proof shows that the claim is true in a more general setting (topological).
Metrics are not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this answer before Mark finished his, but maybe it will still be helpful.

Let $U \subset X$ be an open set containing $p$.

Since $x_n \to p$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $x_n \in U$. In particular, this means $x_N \in U \cap V_{N + 1} \subset U \cap V$. Thus $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

Suppose for contradiction that $p \in V$. This means that $p \in V_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $V_k$ is open and $x_n \to p$, there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq M$ implies $x_n \in V_k$. Set $K = \max\{M, k\}$. Then $x_K \in V_k$ and $x_K \in X \setminus V_K \subset X \setminus V_k$, which is absurd. We conclude that $p \not\in V$. Thus $U \cap (X \setminus V) \neq \emptyset$.

We have shown that any open set containing $p$ intersects with $V$ and $X \setminus V$. Therefore, by definition, $p \in \partial V$.